# Tax Zone Exempt Override

Tags: customization, acumatica

I have custom code for Acumatica on the Sales Order screen where if someone overrides the default shipping address then it will also override the Tax Zone to the zip code provided in the overridden shipping address. However, when the Tax Zone should be Exempt which we have added to the Tax Zones then it should not override this Tax Zone. Here is my code:

```
  namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
  public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
  {
    #region Event Handlers
private bool setCustomTaxZoneID = false;
        protected void SOShippingAddress_PostalCode_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e,
            PXFieldUpdated del)
        {
            SOShippingAddress row = e.Row as SOShippingAddress;
            if (row != null && sender.Locate(row) != null && 
                row.OverrideAddress == true && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.PostalCode))
            {
                var order = Base.Document.Current;
                order.OverrideTaxZone = true;
                setCustomTaxZoneID = true;

            }

            try
            {
                if (del != null)
                {
                    del(sender, e);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                setCustomTaxZoneID = false;
            }
        }

        protected void SOOrder_TaxZoneID_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e,
            PXFieldDefaulting del)
        {
            SOOrder row = e.Row as SOOrder;
            if (row != null && setCustomTaxZoneID && row.OverrideTaxZone == true)
            {
                var shippingAddress = (SOShippingAddress)Base.Shipping_Address.Select();
                var location = (SOOrder)Base.CurrentDocument.Select();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(shippingAddress.PostalCode))
                {

                    var taxZoneZip = PXSelect<TaxZoneZip,
                        Where<TaxZoneZip.zipCode, Equal<Required<TaxZoneZip.zipCode>>>>
                        .Select(Base, shippingAddress.PostalCode)
                        .RowCast<TaxZoneZip>().OrderBy(z => z.TaxZoneID).FirstOrDefault();
                  var cust = PXSelect<Location, Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerID>>>>.Select(Base, location.TaxZoneID);
                    if (taxZoneZip != null && cust != "EXEMPT")
                    {
                        e.NewValue = taxZoneZip.TaxZoneID;
                    }
                }
                return;
            }

            if (del != null)
            {
                del(sender, e);
            }
        }

    #endregion
  }
}
```

The error I get is this:

```
Building directory '\WebSiteValidationDomain\App_RuntimeCode\'.
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(92): error CS0019: Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'PX.Data.PXResultset<PX.Objects.CR.Location>' and 'string'
\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs(92): error CS0019: Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'PX.Data.PXResultset<PX.Objects.CR.Location>' and 'string'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that error `Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'PX.Data.PXResultset<PX.Objects.CR.Location>' and 'string'` is generated when you compare the `cust` variable with the `"EXEMPT"` string constant:

```
if (taxZoneZip != null && cust != "EXEMPT")
{
    ...
}
```

Probably you should be comparing some `taxZoneZip` field value with a string constant, like so:

```
taxZoneZip.TaxZoneID != "EXEMPT"
```

Comment: This did work but I wanted the field not be editable at all if the TaxZoneID was set to Exempt. But the solution does work above.